# Is there an equivalent of Struts token validation in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2

I am seeing duplicate form submission issues in spring. Wanted to implement what is already there in Struts, token validator to check for duplicate requests.

In my form currently, when the user submits a form, instead of submitting and redirecting the page, it makes 2 JSON calls for validation and then submits the form, creating scope for duplicate form submission.

I wanted to use tokens to validate each request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, I think, but:

- http://explodingjava.blogspot.com/2009/03/spring-mvc-synchronizer-token.html

IMO the post-redirect-get or simple JS disable of submit may be enough, unless you're explicitly trying to handle back-button issues and your form page is cached.

Comment: Yeah. Back button is one of the issues. Some users with slow internet connection are able to hit the back button and resubmit. Could form page cache be an issue? Could back button auto-trigger auto-submit of the form. We are seeing weird issues, wherein users report pressing back button. However we see duplicate records created at the same timestamp (down to even smallest second)

Comment: @SmilesinaJar That's why you do post-redirect-get, so hitting the back button doesn't resubmit (although browsers usually pop up a dialog).